# Misleading label at the bottom of jobs, has an : but no content underneath it

Tags: bug, status-completed, stack-overflow-jobs

Once I applied for a job it came back and said at the top, "Here are some jobs you might like:".  But as I scrolled the label at the bottom is misleading it says yet again:

"Here are some jobs you might like:"

I know these labels are supposed to work hand in hand (although their design in text size and color is different - this too should be fixed and I posted about this before!).

I think this label at the bottom is misleading.  When I saw it I was expecting a link next to it as it had a colon at the end: "Here are some jobs you might like:"  Strange I thought, others might think more jobs will be listed under it as the colon suggests it.

Here is the beauty:

[image]

Comment: What's that green arrow? Where's my red circle?

Comment: Green means go.

Comment: Are you sure the content is not blocked by AdBlock?

Comment: @Gothdo - there is no content this is a bug as the label is being set to the same text as the first label.  The first label is okay as the list of jobs is directly under it.  But the final label may confuse users as there is NO content after it.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for reporting this! It's been taken care of